# jsdoc3 grouping / add cathegorys

Tags: javascript, documentation, jsdoc3, group

I try to document my "large" node.js backend, which has the following file/folder structure:

```
backend
├── components
│   ├── devices
│   ├── endpoints
│   ├── plugins
│   ├── rooms
│   └── vault
├── helper
│   ├── debounce.js
│   ├── expose.js
│   ├── extend.js
│   ├── infinity.js
│   ├── iterate.js
│   ├── mixins.js
│   ├── observe.js
│   ├── promisify.js
│   ├── propertys.js
│   ├── queue.js
│   ├── request.js
│   ├── sanitize.js
│   └── timeout.js
├── index.js
└── system
    ├── component
    ├── hooks.js
    └── middleware.js
```

Basically i want to create tree groups: `system`, `helper` & `components`, where i can add.
Is there a way to add custom categorys/groups in the jsdoc with the above headlines? E.g. (Generated jsdoc output edited to illustrate goal):

[image]

Is there a built in way with a combination of built in stuff?
(Im pretty new when it comes to work with jsdoc)